# How to make a stroke that is separated from its object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, stroke

I want to make a stroke to be a little bit further than the object itself, so between object and stroke there will be a transparency.

By default, the stroke is touching the object. **How can I achieve a stroke that is distant from the object in Illustrator?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your strokeless shape and seek out your `Appearance` panel. In there, you'll find the option to `Add a new stroke`, either in the options, or using the button:

[image: appearance panel with add stroke options highlighted]

- Add a new stroke by choosing either option
- Once you've added the new stroke, select it in the panel.

[image: appearance panel with extra stroke selected]

- Choose `Effect > Path > Offset path` and choose a positive value.

Comment: why didnt you offset default stroke?

Comment: @joojaa force of habit :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an object with a stroke (shortcut <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, click)
2. `Object > Path > Offset Path`
3. Remove the fill of the new object (shortcut <kbd>/</kbd>)